# Powershell: batch rename files, add counter in front (with leading 0)

Tags: powershell-ise

I am trying (as so many others) to batch rename files in a folder, by adding a counter to the front of the filename with leading zeros.

Here is what I have:

> b.txt
>   c.txt
>   ... 
>   zzz.txt

Here is what I want:

> 001_b.txt
>   002_c.txt
>   ... 
>   893_zzz.txt

My code so far:

```
$originalFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\abc\" -Filter *.txt
$i = 1

ForEach ($originalFile in $originalFiles) {
    Rename-Item -Path $originalFile.FullName -NewName (($originalFile.Directory.FullName) + "\" + $i + $originalFile.Name)
    $i++
}
```

I am missing the underscore between the the number and the filename. And I am missing the leading zeros.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Sorry for this basic question, this is my first PowerShell experience.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$MyPath = "C:\Users\abc\"
$i=1
Get-ChildItem -Path $MyPath -Filter "*.txt" | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName (Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath "$('{0:d3}' -f $i)_$($_.Name)")
    $i++
}
```

Keep in mind that if you will have 1000 or more files, you will need more than 3 digits